# HTML5 + cordova

Tags: php, javascript, html5, авторизация, cordova

Добрый день вопрос по разработке мобильного приложения на **html5**.

C использованием IntelXDK написал приложение. Регистрация соответственно на php и MySql, как его привязать к приложению, если он будет на тлф, т.е. как сделать авторизацию и регистрацию в приложении. Я так понимаю, что php обработчик мы должны оставить на удаленном сервере, но сделав так и напрямую обратившись результата "0".

Я разместил php скрипт на `mysite.ru/logIn.php` и в js отправляю

```
$.post('http:// mysite. ru/logIn.php', {}, function(){});
```

Comment: При использовании Denwer все работает

Comment: Если Вы пытаетесь отправить этот запрос из браузера на ПК, оно и не будет работать, т.к. браузеры запрещают кросдоменные POST запросы. На мобильном устройстве все должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал - помогло